# Should robots.txt be obeyed for HEAD requests?

Tags: header, web-crawler, robots.txt

I have a list of URLs and wish to find whether they redirect to some other place or not, and if it does, what is their final location. This I am doing by sending **HEAD requests** to these URLs.

The list contains links to certain hosts which disallow my bot (any bot in general) in **robots.txt**.

My question is, in order to be polite-

1. should I follow robots.txt for HEAD requests too, and stop requesting these hosts ?
2. if there is a crawl delay mentioned in robots.txt, should I obey it for these HEAD requests ?
3. is there a web-service that can do this job for me and return the final URLs for a batch of input URLs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should **always** abide by robots.txt, even for HEAD requests. If you don't do so not only are you violating the politeness preferences of the website but you're risking having your IP blocked permanently from the website. A simple HEAD request to a restricted and non-humanly-accessible directory/page on a website can put you on the operator's ban list.

> 1. should I follow robots.txt for HEAD requests too, and stop requesting these hosts ?

You should follow robots.txt or if you're already banned, then stop requesting those hosts.

> 1. if there is a crawl delay mentioned in robots.txt, should I obey it for these HEAD requests ?

Yes.

> 1. is there a web-service that can do this job for me and return the final URLs for a batch of input URLs ?

I don't know of any, but perhaps you can adopt an existing crawler to do that. What programming language do you prefer?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My preferred language would be python or java.